# Testing Rails' new strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just upgraded to Rails 4, and I have started using strong parameters over protected attributes. I typically tested a models protected attributes using unit tests, but I am unsure how to test now that this functionality has been moved to the controller.

I am using rspec for testing. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do

```
post :create, model: { someattrs }
response.response_code.should == 400
```

In your controller spec?

Comment: This is what I will likely do. I am just curious if there are any established best practices out there. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Max Strong params are controller behavior, this is generally the best practice in testing response from controllers. Also check out http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html, where it says that the strong params should return 400 errors. Seems like the best way to test it.